# invalid_grant when using grant type "authorization_code"

Tags: c#, soundcloud

Hi I am getting an error of "invalid_grant" when trying to use a grant_type of "authorization_code".

Here is the url I use for the OAuth2 authorization endpoint:
https://soundcloud.com/connect?client_id=myClientId&redirect_uri=http://www.bing.com&response_type=code&scope=non-expiring

Here is my message body for the OAuth2 token endpoint:

```
Dictionary<string, string> messageBody = new Dictionary<string, string>();
messageBody.Add("client_id", clientId);
messageBody.Add("client_secret", clientSecret);
messageBody.Add("redirect_uri", "http://www.bing.com");
messageBody.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
messageBody.Add("code", code);
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to sort it! Changing the response_type in the first URL to be "token" rather than "code" yields a token that can be used for subsequent requests. You don't even need to do the second post part with an access_code as you already have a token!